# How to create small window in the corner of the screen

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to create a bot using c#, in Visual Studio. What i am struggling to do is that i am trying to create a small box in the corner of the screen while the bot is running, a like the one in the picture:[image: box]

Also, i would like it to be permanently in the corner of screen, so it cant be a window. What i mean by this is that if i was to click away from the box and away from the screen then the box should still be visible.

Comment: In order to be displayed independently on the screen, it **has** to be a window. You can't write directly to the desktop itself. There's no reason it wouldn't be visible if the user clicks somewhere away from there.

Comment: @KenWhite if it was a seperate window, then when a user clicks onto a different window, then that window would be brought to the front

Comment: It **still** has to be a separate window to show as you're asking. There isn't any alternative. You can set your window to be always on top, but any other application can also ask for that as well, and there's no guarantee which will win that argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the window to be placed in the lower right corner of the screen, this code will help:

```
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        this.TopMost = true;
        var screen = Screen.FromPoint(this.Location);
        this.Location = new Point(screen.WorkingArea.Right - this.Width, screen.WorkingArea.Top);
        base.OnLoad(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You want the `TopMost` property on a regular Form.

Answer (score -1):

I simply set the Maximum Size to 1,1. On my screen a 5mm square window showed up.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).